# ImageView will not trigger after click on the image, but will trigger after click on TextView

Tags: android, animation, imageview, rotation

I have an ImageView in my xml file, i want to rotate the image when it's clicked.

I use the following code to archive this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Animation an = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f, img.getWidth() / 2,
                    img.getHeight() / 2);
            an.reset();
            // Set the animation's parameters
            an.setDuration(1000); // duration in ms
            an.setRepeatCount(0); // -1 = infinite repeated
            an.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // reverses each repeat
            an.setFillAfter(true); // keep rotation after animation
            //an.start();
            img.setAnimation(an);


        }
        return true;
    }
```

But te problem is, when i press on the image nothing happens, the image won't turn. But if i click on the image and after that click on a TextView, the image does rotate.

This is so random.

What am i doing wrong? How can i fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that you are calling the onTouchEvent function for your whole activity. Thus, any touch action not "consumed" by a view inside your activity window will trigger this function. So it would be logical that you touching somewhere on your activity such as your TextView would trigger this image rotation thing.

My best guess seeing your code would be this: it would be best to implement a touch/click event listener **for your ImageView itself**, not for your whole Activity. Here is a code snippet that does this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*YOUR CUSTOM CODE AT ACTIVITY CREATION HERE*/

    /*here we implement a click listener for your ImageView*/
    final ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Animation an = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f, img.getWidth() / 2, img.getHeight() / 2);
            an.reset();
            /* Set the animation's parameters*/
            an.setDuration(1000); // duration in ms
            an.setRepeatCount(0); // -1 = infinite repeated
            an.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // reverses each repeat
            an.setFillAfter(true); // keep rotation after animation
            //an.start();
            img.setAnimation(an);
            img.invalidate(); //IMPORTANT: force image refresh

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Note: your onTouch code would have worked if you included the `img.invalidate()` call at the end of your function, although it still doesn't remove the problem where clicking on your `TextView` starts the animation as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't solve it. I still can't trigger the animation by clicking on the image and the image still triggers when i click on a TextView.

Comment: I just tested it on my codebase, and it did work fine. Did you use the img.setOnClickListener as seen above? Did you call invalidate immediately after setting the animation?

Answer (score 0):

I would second the recommendation by epichoms (using an OnClickListener).  Also, make sure your ImageView can receive clicks:

```
final ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
img.setClickable(true);
img.setFocusable(true);
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    ...
```

You can set these values in your XML layout as well:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```